# Corda move tokens from account to party (account hosted in different party)

Tags: corda

Our Corda network has 3 nodes in addition to the notary.
The image shows what each node should do.

[image: Corda nodes]

Only in this scenario we are in trouble "Need to move tokens from account holder to Party B"

Flow code:

```
    class TransferETokenDiffNodeFlow(val actualHolder: AbstractParty,
                                     val newHolder: AbstractParty,
                                     val numEtokens: Double,
                                     val observables: MutableList = mutableListOf()) :
            FlowLogic() {
    
        private fun notary() = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first()
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
    
        progressTracker.currentStep = INITIALIZING
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary())
    
        val actualHolderStateRef = accountService.accountInfo(actualHolder.owningKey)
                ?: throw AccountNotFoundException("Account not found exception.")
        val actualHolderInfo = actualHolderStateRef.state.data
    
        val actualHolderSession = initiateFlow(actualHolderInfo.host)
    
        actualHolderSession.send(numEtokens)
        actualHolderSession.send(actualHolder)
        actualHolderSession.send(newHolder)
    
        val inputs = subFlow(ReceiveStateAndRefFlow(actualHolderSession))
        val tokens: List = actualHolderSession.receive>().unwrap { it -> it}
    
        progressTracker.currentStep = BUILDING
        addMoveTokens(txBuilder, inputs, tokens)
    
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING
        val initialSignedTrnx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
    
        progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
        val fulySignedTx= subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(initialSignedTrnx, listOf(actualHolderSession)))
    
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_CREATE
        val stx = subFlow(FinalityFlow(fulySignedTx, listOf(actualHolderSession)))
    
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING
        val statesTx = stx.tx.outRefsOfType()
        statesTx.forEach { state ->
            observables.forEach { observable ->
                subFlow(ShareStateAndSyncAccounts(state, observable))
            }
        }
    
        return stx
    }
    }
    
    
    //ResponderFlow code:
    class TransferETokenDiffNodeFlowResponder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
    
        val numEtokens = counterpartySession.receive().unwrap { it }
        val actualHolder = counterpartySession.receive().unwrap { it }
        val newHolder = counterpartySession.receive().unwrap { it }
    
        val partyAndAmount = PartyAndAmount(newHolder, numEtokens of EnergyTokenType.getInstance("ENERGY"))
    
        val actualHolderStateRef = accountService.accountInfo(actualHolder.owningKey)
                ?: throw AccountNotFoundException("Account not found exception.")
        val actualHolderInfo = actualHolderStateRef.state.data
        val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(externalIds = listOf(actualHolderInfo.identifier.id),
                status = Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
    
        val selector = DatabaseTokenSelection(serviceHub)
    
        val (inputs, outputs) = selector.generateMove(listOf(partyAndAmount).toPairs(),
                actualHolder, TokenQueryBy(queryCriteria = criteria), runId.uuid)
    
        subFlow(SendStateAndRefFlow(counterpartySession, inputs))
    
        counterpartySession.send(outputs)
    
        subFlow(object : SignTransactionFlow(counterpartySession) {
            @Throws(FlowException::class)
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {
            }
        })
    
        return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(counterpartySession))
    }
    }
```

We need to execute the flow at Party C and the actualHolder is the account holder and the newHolder is Party B.

With this code the returns an error:
net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants: [O = Party B, L = Curitiba, C = BR]

But if I change the code and add the Party B session, it returns the error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must pass in exactly the sessions required to sign the transaction.

The question is, why doesn't addMoveTokens put newHolder as a required signer?
And how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many points to discuss in your code; let's start with the error:

1. When you move tokens, the only required signer is the current holder; so in your case you should pass only one `FlowSession` which is the session with `PartyA` (since it's the holder of the tokens); so you should only have:

   ```kotlin
   CollectSignaturesFlow(initialSignedTrnx, listOf(actualHolderSession))
   ```
2. As for finalizing the transaction, sessions for **all participants** must be passed. The union of all participants in your case is the current holders of the tokens (i.e. `PartyA`) and the new holders (i.e. `PartyB`); so you should have:

   ```kotlin
   FinalityFlow(fulySignedTx, listOf(actualHolderSession, partyB))
   ```

   That's why when you passed only `actualHolderSession` for both sub-flows; you received that a session is missing (because finality flow wants a session for `PartyB` as well); and when you added `PartyB` session for both, the collect signatures flow complained that you're passing an extra session (`PartyB` isn't required to sign the move command, only the current holder is).
3. Since your responder flow is handling both tasks (signing and finalizing); you must send from the initiator to the responder some data (String or whatever you choose) to signify the role of the responder, so for `PartyA` you would send `SignerAndFinalizer`; while for `PartyB` you send `Finalizer`; and in the beginning of your responder, you receive the "role" and act accordingly (i.e. if it's `Finalizer` you don't call `SignTransactionFlow`, only `ReceiveFinalityFlow`).

Now to other topics:

1. I don't recommend that a party moves tokens that are held by another party. Imagine you  own money in your account, and I move that money from your account. It should be the node that holds the tokens that initiates the move. Actually that's how the ready flows of the SDK operate.

   If you look at the `AbstractMoveTokensFlow` you will see that they only sign the transaction locally by relying on `ObserverAwareFinalityFlow` (see [here](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/ad257bda46028d370da49f1de75a6eb2eb3adfcc/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/workflows/flows/move/AbstractMoveTokensFlow.kt#L58-L63)); to confirm that, you can see that inside `ObserverAwareFinalityFlow` there is no `CollectSignaturesFlow` (i.e. it doesn't request signatures from other nodes), only signs locally (see [here](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/ad257bda46028d370da49f1de75a6eb2eb3adfcc/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/workflows/internal/flows/finality/ObserverAwareFinalityFlow.kt#L71-L73)).

   What this all means is that if you used the ready flow of the SDK to move tokens that are held by a node different than the node that's calling the move flow; you'll get an error, because the signature of the holder is required, but the ready flow doesn't collect signatures from other nodes, only from the node that called the move flow, which isn't the holder of the tokens.

   I recommend following the approach of the SDK, in that only the holder of the tokens can move their tokens.
2. Another things mentioned by the Accounts library documentation is not to mix using accounts and non-accounts (i.e. only move from account to account or from party to party); it is advisable instead to create a "default" account for your node (e.g. create an account with a name that matches the X500 name of your node), read [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md#how-do-we-mix-workflows-with-accounts-and-non-accounts).

Comment: Hi, your solution worked perfectly.
I agree about the network mapping, we should use it as the SDK works. But for business rules of the application, we had to model the corda network like this.
About the mix of accounts and nodes, were bugs reported in this use? Because we use it like that and everything is working.
That is, in fact are there any bugs identified or is it just a recommendation from R3?
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe there are bugs, but back in the day (they updated the documentation now) they had this quote: Currently, if accounts and non-accounts workflows are mixed on the same node then you need to be careful with state selection. When selecting states for non-accounts workflows, the state selection code will currently pick states which could be assigned to accounts.

Comment: So basically you might be querying to select tokens that belong to `PartyA` and you might end up selecting tokens that belong to an account hosted on `PartyA`.
I think for your peace of mind, it's better to create an account for `PartyA` (call it `PartyA` or the X500 name of your node, whatever that is).

Comment: In fact we had this scenario, in our network Party A can also receive tokens and it hosts the accounts. We did a workaround to solve it.
We made a vaultquery of FungibleToken and only considered the states that holder is Party to be valid.
I agree that using default accounts is the best approach.